# I get single image instead of animation

Tags: rendering, video

I have a simple scene in Blender 2.8 where there is only one object moving. It's a .png file with default rigid body settings. I'm trying to save this as a video but when I select AVI JPG as an output format:

[image: output_settings]

instead of getting multiple frames rendered and saved I get the same result as if I had .png as an output format - only one frame is rendered and then nothing happens...

Does anyone know what settings should I change to save it as a video?

Comment: Did you render using "render animation" (Ctrl F12)?

Comment: I totally forgot about Ctrl and I was using F12 instead... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use "render animation" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>)